# onhover background color does not appear fully on link

Tags: html, css

I've posted my codes on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cv7PL/). Problem is if i hover a link that background color does not appear fully. Background color only appears for the text only. i want that background color should appear based on the particular width and height of the link.

HTML :

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul class="menubar">
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link2</a>
            <ul class="sidemenu">
                <li><a href="#">sub1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
body
{
    background: rgba(120,120,120,0.1);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#logo
{
    height: 50px;
}
#menu
{
    background-color: #CC0000;
    height: 40px;
}
.menubar
{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.menubar li
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px 5px 20px;
}
.menubar li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.menubar li a:hover
{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
.sidemenu
{
    display: none;
}
.menubar li:hover .sidemenu
{
    display: block;
}
.sidemenu
{
    background-color: #CC0000;
    position: absolute;
    height: 40px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 100px;
}

.sidemenu li a:hover
{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
```

Comment: your hover is applied to a tag only, change this .menubar li a:hover to .menubar li:hover, it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you apply the effect on the `<li>`, the hover effect will work, but the dropdown won’t show until your mouse is perfectly placed on the link itself. This can be confusing for the user since the effect and the result differ.

I suggest you apply the padding to the link instead so the link area is bigger. It fix the visual problem and also improve the experience.

```
.menubar li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.menubar li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Here’s [a complete Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cv7PL/4/) with some extra fixes to your dropdowns.

Answer (score 2):

Simply change this:

```
.menubar li a:hover
```

To this:

```
.menubar li:hover
```

This will apply the background to the whole list item when hovered.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cv7PL/1/).

Answer (score 1):

change

```
.sidemenu li a :hover
{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
```

with

```
.sidemenu li:hover
{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Cv7PL/3/)